# Subtitles not showing using WebVTT

Tags: html5-video

So I'm trying to add subtitles to a html5 video and found WebVTT. I've done some research on it and have even copied some example code to see if that'll work and yet I have no luck.

The subtitles just simply don't show up on the video.

Here's the HTML.

```
<video id="video"  class="video" controls>
              <source src="solar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="client2.ogv" type="video/ogv">
              <source src="solar.webm" type="video/webm">
              <source src="solar.flv" type="video/flv">

              <track label="English Captions" kind="captions" srclang="en" src="english-subtitles.vtt">
        </video>
```

and the test VTT file.

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:13,00 --> 00:00:16,000
Man did you see that awesome thing like last week -

2
00:00:16,100 --> 00:00:20,100
- and i said wow a lot of people are starting to talk about this.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It doesn't work locally, you need to run it on a server.

Answer (score 5):

You use the incorrect time-stamp format. There should a `.` (dot), after the second value.

It should be like this: `00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000`

Comment: Yes , dot "." are used in WebVTT,  I Guess you was using SRT and did not convert it right, cause SRT Uses comma ","

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem you were having.

The problem is that Chrome has a security feature that does not allow files to run local files in Chrome.

The solution is to [run Chrome with the allow local access flag](http://chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/). The link gives instructions for each OS.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers do not support that feature locally

Except Mozilla Firefox 66.0.2

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Safari Browser also can run subtitles WebVTT, and yes with several trials on many browsers and many adjustments only safari and Firefox capable of running WebVTT